# Set values on Select2 search form for multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json string that I wish to add to select2 multiselect search input. I am getting map error as below

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

The json field from console log is

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Test Test"},{"id":2,"name":"Billy A"}]
```

And the js code is

```
   var employees = $(this).attr('data-employees'); 
    console.log(employees);

    $("select[name='employees[]']").val(employees.data.map(function(x) {
   return x.id; })); // Set the selected data before show it.
            $('select').select2()
```

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="employees[]" id="form-field-select-4" width="200px "class="form-control search-select"></select>
```

Comment: If the cosole.log of `employees` gives you the provided array of objects from your question, simple remove the data and do it like that `.val(employees.map(function(x) { ...`

Comment: When data is removed, i get "employees.map is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are getting this array from element attribute and if you are, probably the console.log is a string so, try this:

```
var employees = JSON.parse( $(this).attr('data-employees') ); 
console.log(employees);

$('select').select2(); // init with select2
$("select[name='employees[]']").val(employees.map(function(x) {
   return x.id;  // Set the selected data before show it.
}))
.trigger("change");
```

If you see this

```js
var employees = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"name":"Test Test"},{"id":2,"name":"Billy A"}]');
console.log('The whole array:', employees); // you have a valid array

var ids = employees.map(function(x){ return x.id; })
console.log('Employee ids only: ', ids);
```

Edited

Comment: No longer getting an error as such. The console.log for this returns [Object, Object]. The modal select field is blank without the values.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you have seen this in your console.log as well, you problem is somewhere else ;].

Comment: True. I have seen your results. My issue is elsewhere to place the data in the select box. I am guessing something is incomplete on line: $('select').select2()

Comment: Try to initialize it with `.select2()` first then select selected values, see the code aboove. Thats what I can help you